# Asynchronous output to textbox in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, visual-studio

I've got a foreach loop running in C# asp.net project which is run on server side.

After every iteration of the loop is complete i would like to update a textbox (consolebox.text) on the client web browser so the user can see that a loop has completed.

It only updates the textbox after the function is complete so the user doesn't see the progress output till the whole foreach is completed. Below is my code, i've tried ajax updatepanels to no avail

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        consolebox.Text = "Please Wait........"+ Environment.NewLine;


            foreach (var listBoxItem in serverlist.Items)
                {
                    string send = listBoxItem.ToString();
                    DELETEPROFILE(send);
                    consolebox.Text += ("" + send + "........Complete" + Environment.NewLine);

                }


    }
```

Comment: I think the easiest way is updating the textbox via javascript before calling the server side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it by web service. Use ajax to start functioning and other service to read functioning.

Sample:

Aspx

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
        function ajaxCall(fsMathod) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Test.aspx/" + fsMathod,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: OnSuccess,
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.d);
                }
            });
        }
        function OnSuccess(response) {
            alert(response.d);
            var TheTextBox = document.getElementById("<%=consolebox.ClientID%>");
            TheTextBox.value = TheTextBox.value + response.d;
        }
    </script>
    <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div style="margin:0 auto; width:20%">
        Textbox: <asp:TextBox ID="consolebox" TextMode="MultiLine" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />

        <input id="btnStartAsync" type="button" value="Start Async" onclick = "ajaxCall('startAsync');" />
        <input id="btnReadAsync" type="button" value="Read Async" onclick = "ajaxCall('readAsync')" />

    </div>

    </form>
</body>
```

c#

```
static string CompletedItems = "";
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
        public static string readAsync()
        {
            return "" + CompletedItems + "........Complete\n";
        }

        [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
        public static void startAsync()
        {
            asyncTask();
        }

        private static void asyncTask()
        {
            foreach (var listBoxItem in serverlist.Items)
            {
                string send = listBoxItem.ToString();
                DELETEPROFILE(send);
                //consolebox.Text += ("" + send + "........Complete" + Environment.NewLine);
                CompletedItems += send + ",";
            }
        }
```